# Google Analytics Funnel Goal Funnel using RegEx

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking, regular-expression, regex

I've created goals using Google Analytics to track the number of pageviews and goal conversions. I have 2 goals in mind.

First Goal: User made an appointment without going to other sites > Thank you for making an appt page

Second Goal: User who read a page with article > made an appointment > Thank you for making an appt page

However, the number of page view collected for goal 1 and goal 2 are the same, which is not possible as this suggests that everyone read the article before making an appointment.

I think something is wrong with my RegEx. Can anyone help? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the thank you page is the same url for both goals, then anyone reaching the thank you page will show as a goal conversion in the goal reports.

Goal funnels only affect the goal funnel report.

I would also change the regex. ATM your not using regular expressions for the goal urls, you simply have urls entered.

Assuming none of the pages have parameters appended after what is entered in your screen shot, I would change the goal destination url to:

```
^/make-an-appointment/thank-you$
```

and step1 to:

```
^/articletwo
```

and step2 to

```
^/make-an-appointment$
```

Another alternative is to set up a single destination goal and then create a sequence segment to segment the data for more granuality, basing the sequence segment on a session, where the article page was viewed first, followed by the goal completion.

Unfortunately the info in the GA Help Center on sequence segments is very limited, however the following article is a great guide for familiarizing yourself with them.
https://www.bounteous.com/insights/2016/04/04/sequence-segments-more-accurate-reporting/

Comment: Ha, I barely started an answer when I got called away and you got to it first. :-) I was going to link to a different Bounteous article: https://www.bounteous.com/insights/2014/10/21/goals-funnels-confusion-google-analytics/
It's a little technical but discusses the fact that funnels are ignored when counting conversions, and some ways to get the data you want anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I think the biggest mistake I made here is equating The Funnel Conversion Rate to the Goal Conversion Rate. I have made changes accordingly and it should work now.